# How does modulo operation work in terms of the remainder of long division with negative dividends?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic

I'm trying to figure out how the modulo operation works using long division with negative dividends.

I know that $-1 \bmod 10 = 9$. But I can't figure out why.

For positive dividends, it's relatively straightforward.

$1 \bmod 10$  is the remainder of the long division of $1 ÷ 10$, which is $1$.

[image: long division of 1 /÷10]

But when I try to find the remainder of the long division of $-1 ÷ 10$, I get $-1$, not $9$.

[image: long division of -1 /÷10]

What am I doing wrong or failing to grasp?

Answer (score 3):

When we divide $a$ by $b$ we can write $a=qb+r$ where $q$ is the quotient and $r$ is the remainder.  We usually define $r \in [0,b-1]$ and it looks like you are doing so.  In that case we write $-1=-1\cdot 10+9$, so the quotient is $-1$ and the remainder is $9$.  You want the largest multiple of $b$ that is less than $a$.  In your example that is $-10$, not $0$ as $0 \not \lt -1$